# Why was this question involving Survival Functions migrated to Stat.Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401600/8671

It's essentially a basic actuarial science question.  Most of the tags don't fit.  I'd say actuarial science and probability fit but the other three don't.  I'm guessing it was migrated because the people didn't understand what it was talking about.  But, everything it was talking about is standard actuarial science knowledge.  In fact, it's standard terminology on exams MLC and C in the Society of Actuaries, both of which are preliminary exams.

So, are questions like this not allowed here?  Or, did the migraters not understand what it was talking about?

Comment: I'd think it fits here, but it might be better served at CV.

Answer (score 4):

The question was more about the terminology and assumptions than the actual mathematical manipulation, so I believed it was more likely to receive a good answer at CV.  (Which it did, by the way.)

Comment: That's fine.  But, I would like to point out there are several people on this site that know that stuff as well.  I know many actuarial science professors are actually math PhDs, not statistics PhDs.  Andre often answers actuarial science questions.  And, this site has many more people, does it not, so I think that might help it have a better chance here than there.  Just because it happened to receive an answer there does not make that place better.  I provided an answer with much more detail than the other answer, and I could have done that here as well.